# What do i need to do to access global data in a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an angular app, defined as follows with some global values:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'services'])
    .value('GlobalValues',
    {
        host : "http://localhost/",
        accountApi: 'MyService/api/AccountApi/'

        // ... other stuff like this
    })
    .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
        // etc..
    })
```

I'm able to access `GlobalValues` in my `UserService`, which is defined as:

```
angular.module('services', [])
    .service('UserService', function($q, $http, $ionicLoading, GlobalValues) {
        alert(GlobalValues.host); // has a value
    });
```

But in my `CreateAdController`, `GlobalValues` is undefined:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ionicApp')
        .controller('CreateAdController', ['$cordovaCamera', 'Camera', '$scope', '$http', 'GlobalValues', CreateAdController]);

    function CreateAdController($cordovaCamera, $scope, $http, GlobalValues) {
        alert(GlobalValues.host); // is undefined!
    };
})();
```

What do I need to do to access the data in `GlobalValues` from my `CreateAdController`?

Comment: injection problem. GlobalValues is fifth paramter but you only inject 4 paramters to controller...

Comment: The order of modules you inserted and the function sending the modules is not correct. GlobalValues will contain $http object as per the above code.

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz is right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('ionicApp')
    .controller('CreateAdController', ['$cordovaCamera', 'Camera', '$scope', '$http', 'GlobalValues']);

function CreateAdController($cordovaCamera, Camera, $scope, $http, GlobalValues) {
    alert(GlobalValues.host); // is undefined!
};
})();
```

The above should work I have made some changes. Also CreateAdController need not be injected again

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with your injections. There are a few values too much in your injection statement or to little in your method signature.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ionicApp')
        .controller('CreateAdController', ['$cordovaCamera', 'Camera', '$scope', '$http', 'GlobalValues']);

    function CreateAdController($cordovaCamera, Camera,  $scope, $http, GlobalValues) {
        alert(GlobalValues.host); // is undefined!
    };
})();
```

Make sure to respect the injector/function signature order.